# Remote Explorer VScode for SSH twice

Tags: ssh, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I'm trying to use VScode "Remote Explorer" extension to work on files located on a nested remote server ("host2") through an intermediate server ("host1").

I can ssh to "host2" using terminal:

```
ssh username1@host1
ssh username2@host2
```

and I have connected to "host1" using the Remote explorer and accessed files there.

However, when I try to SSH from "host1" to "host2" through Remote explorer, it does not work. There is also an error show up

```
Extension 'ms-vscode.remote-explorer' CANNOT use API proposal: localization. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals-property declares: contribViewsRemote, extensionsAny but NOT localization. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api ms-vscode.remote-explorer
```

Any insights or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding

```
Host host2
    HostName host2
    User username2
    ProxyCommand ssh username1@host1 -W %h:%p
```

to ssh config.